# Apache Ant doesn't compile all of my files

Tags: java, build, ant

I have a simple project whose `build.xml` looks like this:

```
<project name="Code Abbey Solutions" default="build">
  <property name = "src" value = "."/>

  <target name="build">
    <javac destdir="${src}">
      <src path = "${src}"/>
    </javac>
  </target>
</project>
```

Now when I ran Ant, one file `Common.java` compiled but the other, `Solution001.java` didn't. Why would that happen?

Comment: Try <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${src}" />

Comment: I've found the embarrassing solution: the file was effectively a stub and contained no classes at the time

Answer (score 0):

In my instance: ensure your file contains at least one class before compilation!